# What's the benefit of an IIFE that returns a value than just using that value?

Tags: javascript, return-value, iife

I had found this code on [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/browser-extension-edge-chrome-firefox-opera-brave-vivaldi/):

```js
window.browser = (function () {
  return window.msBrowser ||
    window.browser ||
    window.chrome;
})();
```

I had noticed that this expression seemed equal to this one:

```js
browser=window.msBrowser||window.browser||window.chrome;
```

> ##### Side note on the above code
>
> It was supposed to be used in a browser extension, but it doesn't work in background scripts because they don't support `window`.  Some other code that should work is:
>
> ```js
> if(typeof msBrowser!=="undefined")var browser=msBrowser;
> else if(typeof chrome!=="undefined")var browser=chrome;
> else if(typeof browser==="undefined")throw "UnsupportedBrowserError";
> ```

Is there a reason that the author had written the code in the way above?  Not knowing the answer, I just decided to keep it the way it is.  If there is a reason, what is it, and if there isn't a reason, would it be safe to use the one line alternative or should I use something else?

Comment: No, no benefit in this case.

Comment: no, you may have some variables named msBrowser or browse or chrome, and your small line will become a nightmare to debugg

Comment: Can you please post an answer (maybe with some elaboration?) so that I can accept the answer?

Comment: "*I had noticed that this expression seemed equal to this one: `browser=msBrowser||browser||chrome;`*" the IIFE and that line are not equivalent. If `msBrowser` is not a variable, for example, your replacement line will throw an error. The equivalent is `window.browser = window.msBrowser || window.browser || window.chrome;`

Comment: @VLAZ: Oops, going to fix that now, thanks for noticing!