# How do you keep a background script (service worker) persistent in Manifest v3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

In Manifest v2, you could just add `"persistent": true` to the `manifest.json` like this:

```json
{
    ...
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    ...
}
```

Normally, it is said to use persistent: false, but right now I need my script to be persistent, without waiting for any events.  I tried searching but it looks like they removed the persistent key and now I need to make my script "event based".

Trying to hack through, I opened a port like this:

```js
// content script
var port=browser.runtime.connect();
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg){
    if(msg===0)port.postMessage(1);
});
setInterval(function(){
    port.postMessage(Math.random());
},1000);
```

```js
// background script
browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg){
        if(msg===1)port.postMessage(Math.random());
    });
    setInterval(function(){
        port.postMessage(Math.random());
    },1000);
});
```

<sup>Side note: I am using `browser` instead of `chrome` to make my extension usable across browsers (using [a check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68122880/14469685), I set `browser` to the current browser, but that's off topic)</sup>

But even with this port that keeps communicating, I see that my background script becomes inactive.  Is there any working method to keep a background script active?

Other information: The reason I need to keep my background script going is because it uses `captureVisibleTab` every second, but when it goes inactive, then it stops taking the screenshots.  I want it to keep going forever, and that's why I want the script to be persistent.

Comment: @wOxxOm: you have closed this question, but the solutions that are given in the other answer don't work (at least for me).  When I tried solution 0, my background script didn't do anything (but did register), in solution 1 the forever ports didn't work, and I don't want a dedicated tab either (solution 2).  Maybe those were for manifest v2?  They didn't really help me in this case.

Comment: Every solution was tested (also by other people) and works in a ManifestV3 extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Hmmm... seems like I'll have to find out how to make it work.  Thanks for the help anyways.  I think I'll try the forever ports, maybe I did something to it that made it stop working (like missing permission, not working with existing code, etc.)

Comment: @LakshyaRaj have you been able to find any solution of the problem so far?

Comment: @user1635430: I did not. You might want to try the solutions in the "duplicate" suggestion. They didn't work for me, but maybe mine is just an exception. (Also sorry for the late response)